# How to add SSL certificates for multiple VPS (Shared Hosting Servers) with the same primary domain?

Tags: email-server, lets-encrypt, hostname

I am planning 3 VPS shared hosting servers.

Of particular focus in this question...they are also acting as mail servers.

host1.mydomain.com
host2.mydomain.com
host3.mydomain.com

(where "mydomain" is identical across the 3 servers)

I am not using cpanel! If i was using cpanel, my understanding is that clients could input mail.clientdomain.com as their incoming and outgoing servers for email...but i dont believe i can do that with SSL without cpanel?

So on my servers, if a lot of clients do not purchase their own ip address, the incoming and outgoing mail server settings for email client apps (such as oultook or apple mail) will likely be host1.mydomain.com or host2.mydomain.com or host3.mydomain.com (with SSL or STARTTLS encryption)

If the SSL certificate on each of the above servers does not match mydomain.com, the email client apps for clients are going to have a meltdown over the mismatch on the mydomain.com if i copy the first virtual host SSL to the host1.mydomain.com and so on across the other 2 servers.

Lets encrypt doesnt seem to want to allow me to just get separate certificates for host1.mydomain.com and host2.mydomain.com and host3.mydomain.com...it throws a missing virtual host error.

What is the workaround for this where i want to maintain my brand name across multiple servers? How do i get letsencrypt to automatically add an SSL cert for each VPS when letsencrypt seems like it requires a vhost in apache for each of them?

i can only add mydomain.com to one server...what about the other 2?

what are my options here?

Is it a single wildcard SSL for *.mydomain.com that is manually copied across to the other 2 servers, or something else?

kind regards
Adam

Comment: "I am not using cpanel! If i was using cpanel, my understanding is that clients could input mail.clientdomain.com as their incoming and outgoing servers for email...but i dont believe i can do that with SSL without cpanel?" - incorrect. Its an amount of work, but you can do this. A single SSL cert can have multiple domains associated with it.

Comment: You can get a wildcard cert *.my domain.com (or just tell all your users to use smtp.your server.com). You would distribute the same SSL certs to all 3 mail servers, as certs "bind to" domain names, not IP addresses.